# What is the best approach to show an 4000x3000 Image in Flutter stateless widget on mobile?

Tags: flutter, performance

I wonder, what is the most efficient (cpu, memory saving) way to simply show an Image to full screen, which is stored on local mobile phone storage:

Option 1: straightforward
Will the image be reloaded and decoded on every widget rebuild?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SizedBox.expand(
      child: Image.asset(
        'assets/images/lake.jpg',
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Option 2: or always use the caching? I assume, it won´t be read again from storage and neither be decoded twice. So is this the best way?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
        body: SizedBox.expand(
      child: Image.asset(
        'assets/images/lake.jpg',
        cacheHeight: size.height.toInt(),
        cacheWidth: size.width.toInt(),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Option 3: or always resize the image size when is to be displayed to the screen? Resizing would reduce memory consumption - but do we have the read-always-again-from-storage and decode hell on every widget update?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
        body: SizedBox.expand(
      child: Image(
        image: ResizeImage(
            Image.asset(
              'assets/images/lake.jpg',
            ).image,
            width: size.width.toInt(),
            height: size.height.toInt()),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Option 4: Or would be a stateful widget be more appropriate? e.g. when the parent widget provides you the screen dimensions as parameters. Here, it is obvious, that the image load and resizing is done only once. So is this the best? However, we have a stateful widget here....

```
  late Image image;

  @override
  void initState() {
    image = Image(
        image: ResizeImage(
            Image.asset(
              'assets/images/lake.jpg',
            ).image,
            width: widget.width,
            height: widget.height));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return image;
  }
```

any further options? :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would propably precache image (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/precacheImage.html) but I have never done it so I am not really sure if its really worth it.

but before that I would downgrade it to the size of device unless you want to have some zoom feature...

Thanks to immutability when stateful widget setState it only rebuilds those widgets that has been changed(point me if Im wrong). So if nothing changed in your "image widget" then it should point to the same object. Of course we get rebuild but it won't do it blindly.

To prevent Stateless widget from rebuilding you can use `const`